# Voronoi diagram from latitude ,longtime points and bounding box using Steven Fortune's code

Tags: gis, geospatial, geojson, voronoi

I'm using http://ageeksnotes.blogspot.com/2010/11/fast-java-implementation-fortunes.html

```
 List<GraphEdge> allEdges = voronoi.generateVoronoi(latValues, lngValues, maxLatitude, minLatitude, minLongitiude, maxLongitude);
```

i have a list of points(lat,long) and the bounding box of those points from these "Graph edges".

List allEdges  should be all i need

```
60.1365210529365,-1.32798132296606
60.1338473169364,-1.33199657348365
60.1392706837279,-1.33043515202468
60.1405725317445,-1.33005929108147
60.1393406902,-1.32942830065997
60.1365210529365,-1.32798132296606

//bounding box.
minLatitude[60.1365210529365]
minLongitiude[-1.32798132296606] 
maxLatitude[60.1405725317445] 
maxLongitude[-1.33199657348365]
```

gives me a colleciton of graphEdges
GraphEdge size [9] 
with results:

```
GraphEdge size [9] 
 SITE 1 [2] x1,y1 [60.1365210529365,-1.330748782763273] 
 SITE 2 [5] x2,y2 [60.13899079297949,-1.32798132296606] 
 SITE 1 [2] x1,y1 [60.1365210529365,-1.330748782763273] 
 SITE 2 [0] x2,y2 [60.13737030236351,-1.3297971588651558] 
 SITE 1 [2] x1,y1 [60.137370302363514,-1.3297971588651558] 
 SITE 2 [4] x2,y2 [60.13984127151547,-1.3299689655876374] 
 SITE 1 [4] x1,y1 [60.137370302363514,-1.3297971588651558] 
 SITE 2 [0] x2,y2 [60.138302150610734,-1.32798132296606] 
 SITE 1 [3] x1,y1 [60.139841271515465,-1.329968965587637] 
 SITE 2 [4] x2,y2 [60.1405725317445,-1.3285413738219385] 
 SITE 1 [1] x1,y1 [60.1365210529365,-1.330879162193689] 
 SITE 2 [5] x2,y2 [60.1365210529365,-1.330879162193689] 
 SITE 1 [3] x1,y1 [60.13907967819445,-1.32798132296606] 
 SITE 2 [0] x2,y2 [60.13907967819445,-1.32798132296606] 
 SITE 1 [2] x1,y1 [60.1404266690477,-1.33199657348365] 
 SITE 2 [3] x2,y2 [60.139841271515465,-1.329968965587637] 
 SITE 1 [1] x1,y1 [60.13678377186855,-1.33199657348365] 
 SITE 2 [2] x2,y2 [60.1365210529365,-1.3310840580808576]
```

how am I suppose to 'visualize this'? i want to make polygons from the original points. the list of  List allEdges should be all I need to generate the polygons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using JTS topology suite to obtain needed output for visualization. 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vividsolutions/jts/1.13

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how would you like to visualize it in which environment and using what software. So i think it is safe to convert the latitude and longitude coordinates into GIS readable file format like shapefile, WKT or GeoJSON etc.

One possible solution is using GeoTools which is also in Java. It has the function ready to convert input into shapefile or other GIS supported formats and later on it can be viewed in various of applications such as GIS web APIs and desktop appications.

Check the following link http://docs.geotools.org/latest/tutorials/

Comment: Hi, im trying to understand how am i to use a list of "GraphEdge" to create the voronoi polygons " List<GraphEdge> allEdges" ...